# Are there any regular expression engines that provide visibility into what they're doing?

Tags: regex

In every programming language I've worked with, regular expression support (if it exists) is basically a black box: there are some functions like `match`, `scan`, etc. that take an expression and return *something*—often a string, or an array—but they don't report on what they're doing *while they're doing it*.

I'm wondering if, in any reasonably popular programming language, there is either built-in or library support for matching regular expressions and providing some kind of real-time output (e.g., to standard out) indicating what's happening.

**Update**: I appreciate the comments so far; however, I'm not asking about a tool that displays the structure *of the regular expression itself*, which is what [debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com/) and [regexper.com](http://www.regexper.com/) appear to do (though that's very cool!). I meant to ask about providing info during the part where the expression is applied to some input.

Here's a hypothetical example: suppose I had the expression "(foo|bar|baz)" and I test this against the string "baz"; then I'm picturing output that might look like...

```
testing "foo" - nope
testing "bar" - nope
testing "baz" - found match
```

Obviously it wouldn't look quite like that; but you get the idea.

Comment: There's this:  http://www.debuggex.com/

It looks like all the code they use is freely available.

Comment: Regular expressions(pure ones) only go through the input once so most of the time a regex is just iterating through the string, I would guess the code looks something like a DFA

Comment: I was about to comment about http://www.regexper.com/ but @MichaelGraczyk's suggestion might be better.

Comment: I doubt there's a programming language that does that, since it'd increase the overhead of regexp handling significantly. That said, a regexp match simply runs through the pattern DFA, so the matching that will happen is pretty much the pattern your wrote being accepted element by element. @MichaelGraczyk's link is great, and really should be an answer rather than a comment =)

Comment: Regarding your edit. Debuggex does that in a way as well. Try out the sliders. Or check out the tutorial video he linked. Otherwise, Regex Buddy can show you something like you're looking for.

Comment: @m.buettner: Ah, cool! Didn't notice that at first.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk Thanks for the link to Debuggex! However, it's not open-sourced, though it does rely on several open-source libraries. Sorry for the miscommunication. I'll make this more clear on the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several regular expression libraries are written in such a way that you can get state by state processing information.  In particular, Russ Cox wrote an article on regular expressions that included bits of code and an API for transitioning state by state:

http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

The code used in the article was expanded into a complete, simple regex library that appears to give step by step output similar to what you described:

https://code.google.com/p/re1/

Later, the code was more fully worked out and is now a full blown regex library maintained (and used internally) by Google:

https://code.google.com/p/re2/

**EDIT**

If you compile re2 with `DebugDFA` set to true in the source code, you will get state by state output during processing. However, for many regex's it may not correspond 1-1 with the actual regular expression, and the output is a little esoteric.

Comment: Ha! I work at Google and read a bit about RE2 a little while ago. Funny that I didn't think of it when asking this question.

Comment: Are you sure this library provides step-by-step output? I see a `log_errors` option, which seems to output errors to sterr; but I'm having trouble finding a way to get output even in successful cases.

Comment: @DanTao I think that was not his point. But if you read those papers you'll have a pretty good idea of how the engine operates internally.

Comment: @DanTao Hmmmm I ran it and saw outputs that were numbered but now I realize that these are the results of several different regex engines listed in order.  It seems that there is no output, but the way it is written it should be easy to add print statements that describe the current NFA state.  I'll try to add those statements and post the changes (or just post my version to github)

Comment: @DanTao Actually I just looked through re2 and I think that if you use re2 with `DebugDFA==1` you will get state by state output during processing, although for many regex's it may not correspond 1-1 with the actual regular expression.

Comment: Aha! Yes, I see: just compiled w/ `DebugDFA` set to true and I see tons of output. It's not exactly "friendly"; but it's a great start. Thanks for pointing me to this.

Comment: Updated answer to mention debugging output.

Answer (score 4):

Python's regular expression engine [does provide visibility](http://jtauber.com/blog/2008/11/03/pythons_re_debug_flag/), using the [RE.debug flag](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DEBUG). You're asking for something different though (realtime feedback) which I'm pretty sure does not exist. I could see it being integrated into an IDE or an enhanced python shell such as [ipython](http://ipython.org). It would be a fun thing to write and quite useful, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

### RegexBuddy

Although not a programming language, [JGSoft's RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/debug.html) utility has a built-in regular expression debugger that shows every step (including every backtrack) the regex engine performs when applied to a given target string. I use this tool to measure and  compare the efficiency of various expressions. Its also quite handy for identifying runaway expressions (i.e. [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)).

Comment: Yes, and worth every penny IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an exact answer to what you're asking, but is related.

If you're looking to do some sort of arbitrary computation using callbacks while a string is being evaluated (like a compiler might do to generate an abstract syntax tree as it parses source code), you can use parsing and lexing tools in almost any popular language. Many of these use regular expressions to define the grammars they will accept, and will be more appropriate for processing complex grammars (definitely overkill for the example you gave, though).